# What does it mean for a contract to "stop"?

Tags: plutus, smart-contract, plutus-pioneer-program, haskell

I'm working through the week 4 homework for the Plutus Pioneer program. I've found an answer to the homework problem and now I'm trying to get a deeper understanding of the code. I've noticed that the `payContract` [returns itself](https://github.com/paymog/plutus-pioneer-program/blob/8471f77119f7815ba9103384a7dd8b9ef0188f91/code/week04/src/Week04/Solution.hs#L33) (I'm still learning Haskell so that terminology might not be correct).

I find that if I comment out this line of code, then the [second invocation of `callEndpoint`](https://github.com/paymog/plutus-pioneer-program/blob/8471f77119f7815ba9103384a7dd8b9ef0188f91/code/week04/src/Week04/Solution.hs#L44) doesn't do anything. I also notice that the logs of `payTest1` say `Contract Stopped`:

```
Prelude Week04.Solution> payTest1
Slot 00000: TxnValidate 0636250aef275497b4f3807d661a299e34e53e5ad3bc1110e43d1f3420bc8fae
Slot 00000: SlotAdd Slot 1
Slot 00001: 00000000-0000-4000-8000-000000000000 {Contract instance for wallet 1}:
  Contract instance started
Slot 00001: 00000000-0000-4000-8000-000000000000 {Contract instance for wallet 1}:
  Receive endpoint call on 'pay' for Object (fromList [("contents",Array [Object (fromList [("getEndpointDescription",String "pay")]),Object (fromList [("unEndpointValue",Object (fromList [("ppLovelace",Number 1000000.0),("ppRecipient",Object (fromList [("getPubKeyHash",String "977efb35ab621d39dbeb7274ec7795a34708ff4d25a01a1df04c1f27")]))]))])]),("tag",String "ExposeEndpointResp")])
Slot 00001: W1: TxSubmit: 66b88e2673c2d50a5de7603fb28c71ac56963d88dda4c69dc529e2d26638b294
Slot 00001: 00000000-0000-4000-8000-000000000000 {Contract instance for wallet 1}:
  Contract instance stopped (no errors)
Slot 00001: TxnValidate 66b88e2673c2d50a5de7603fb28c71ac56963d88dda4c69dc529e2d26638b294
Slot 00001: SlotAdd Slot 2
Slot 00002: SlotAdd Slot 3
Slot 00003: SlotAdd Slot 4
```

I feel like I can intuit what `Contract Stopped` means but I'd like to understand on a more technical level what this means and under which conditions this happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line of interest is:

```
pp <- endpoint @"pay"
```

Which is essentially blocking until someone hits the `"pay"` endpoint and then returning whatever `PayParams` the caller included (see `PaySchema`).

In the case where you include the recursive `payContract` function call, you are essentially saying, "after running `payContract`, wait for someone else to hit the `"pay"` endpoint."

In the case that the recursive `payContract` function call is removed, the `Contract` monad will exit, since it isn't blocked on any endpoints or anything.

Hope that helps :)